# NetworkX: Adding edges to a graph from a dictionary with lists as values

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a question on how to add edges to a graph from a dictionary containing lists as values. 
I want to define a function that takes a dictionary as an argument and then adding an edge for each key+object in the list of values.
I have created the empty graph structure and wonder if there is a smart way to add the entire dictionary.

> > def build_network(dict):
> >
> > ```
> >   G = nx.Graph()
> > ```

After that I just want to return the constructed graph.

I know it is a novice question, but any help will be received gratefully!

Edit 1: The dictionary contains of an football player as key and a list of clubs he have been playing in as value.

Edit 2: The string of the dictionary is in Unicode. An example would be {u'Drogba': [u'Le Mans', u'Chelsea', u'Galatasaray'], u'Beckham: [u'Manchester United', u'Real Madrid', u'Los Angeles Galaxy']}

Comment: "containing lists as values" is a little vague.  An example of your desired input and output would help.

Comment: .. so does your dictionary look like `{"a": ["c0", "c1", "c2"], "b": ["c2", "c4", "c6"]}`?  (Around here by "example" we tend to mean something concrete, something that people can copy and paste to experiment with.  Showing works better than describing.)

Comment: Oh sorry! I have tried to provide an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Graph` object can take a dictionary as an initialization argument, so I think it'll do what you want pretty straightforwardly:

```
>>> d = {'Drogba': ['Le Mans', 'Chelsea', 'Galatasaray'], 'Beckham': ['Manchester United', 'Real Madrid', 'Los Angeles Galaxy']}
>>> g = nx.Graph(d)
>>> g.nodes()
['Manchester United', 'Beckham', 'Real Madrid', 'Le Mans', 'Los Angeles Galaxy', 'Drogba', 'Galatasaray', 'Chelsea']
>>> g.edges("Beckham")
[('Beckham', 'Real Madrid'), ('Beckham', 'Los Angeles Galaxy'), ('Beckham', 'Manchester United')]
>>> g.neighbors("Drogba")
['Galatasaray', 'Chelsea', 'Le Mans']
```

Comment: I have no idea how I could oversee that. Thank you for your answer - and patience ;)